# Prove that a non-zero vector cannot belong to the rowspace and nullspace of a matrix at the same time.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-rank

With research, I've mainly found that rowspace is the orthogonal complement of the nullspace, and the only vector that belongs to both spaces at the same time is {0}.

In the linear algebra subject that I'm doing so far, we have not learnt about orthogonality, and we're only expected to use the materials we've been given up until this point of the subject. More specifically, this is the question that we are to answer:
[image]

What is the proof that the condition given in (1b) is not possible?

Comment: @twosigma Yes, and I know that the result is non-zero vector, so the vector multiplied to the matrix isn't an element of its nullspace. I'm just unsure how that would be sufficient enough proof, since an element of a matrix's rowspace does not necessarily have to be a row vector in the original matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, the question is unfairly ambiguous.  The rowspace of an $\ m\times n\ $ matrix comprises $\ 1\times n\ $ matrices (i.e. *row* vectors), so a $\ 3\times 1\ $ *column* vector such as $\ \mathbf{v}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{bmatrix}\ $ cannot belong to it.

If, however, you interpret the question as instead asking for a matrix $\ \mathbf{A}\ $ such that:

$
\hspace{3em}\mathbf{v}^{\color{red}\top} \in\text{Row }\mathbf{A}
$ and $\ \mathbf{v} \in\text{Nul }\mathbf{A}\ $ at the same time

then you can show this is impossible because it leads to a contradiction:
\begin{align}
\mathbf{v} \in\text{Nul }\mathbf{A}&\Rightarrow\mathbf{Av}=0\ \ \text{ and}\\
\mathbf{v}^\top \in\text{Row }\mathbf{A} &\Rightarrow \mathbf{v}^\top = \mathbf{x}^\top\mathbf{A}\ \ \text{ for some row vector }\mathbf{x}^\top\\
&\Rightarrow \mathbf{v}^\top \mathbf{v}= \mathbf{x}^\top\mathbf{A} \mathbf{v}=0\ ,
\end{align}
which contradicts the fact that $\ \mathbf{v}^\top \mathbf{v}= 1^2+2^2+3^2=14\ $.

Comment: Good answer! After all, multiplying a matrix $A$ on the left by some row vector $x$ to get $xA$ gives us a row vector that is just a linear combination of the rows of $A$, with the coefficients coming from $x$. In other words, to say that $v^T$ (for some column vector $v$) is in the row space of $A$ means that there is some row vector $x$ such that $v^T = xA$.

Comment: Thank you for the correction.  I think I meant to say "for some row vector $\ x^\top\ $".  At any rate, that's what I've now changed it to.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**:

Here is an argument that doesn't use orthogonality: if $v$ is a non-zero vector in the row space, you can apply elementary row operations to $A$ until one of its rows is $v$ (for example,  if $v = a_1 \times \text{(row 1)} + ... + a_m \times \text{(row m)}$ with $a_i \neq 0$ for some $i$, then multiply row $i$ by the non-zero number $a_i$, and add on $a_k \times \text{(row $k$)}$ for each $k \neq i$. Then the new row $i$ will be the vector $v$). But applying elementary row operations corresponds to multiplying $A$ by some invertible matrices, so [this doesn't change the null space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108041/linear-algebra-preserving-the-null-space?rq=1). If $v$ is the $i$th row of the transformed matrix (call it $B$), then the $i$th row of $Bv$ is just the sum of the squared components of $v$, which is non-zero since $v$ is nonzero. So $Bv$ is non-zero, i.e. $v$ is not in the null space of $B$, hence it is also not in the null space of $A$.

---

**Solution 2**:

Once we have inner products (or the dot product, if you like), we can just use the following fact:

**Claim**: Let $U$ be a subspace of a vector space $V$. Let $U^\perp$ denote the orthogonal complement of $U$. Then $U \cap U^\perp = \{ 0 \}$.

**Proof**: Since $U$ and $U^\perp$ are both subspaces, clearly $0 \in U \cap U^\perp$. Hence $\{ 0 \} \subseteq U \cap U^\perp$. Now we show that $U \cap U^\perp \subseteq \{ 0 \}$. Let $v \in U \cap U^\perp$. Then $v$ is orthogonal to itself, i.e. $v \cdot v = 0$, so it must be the zero vector, because all nonzero vectors have positive inner product with themselves (or dot product, if you like). $\square$

This proves your result: since the row space is the orthogonal complement of the null space, they have trivial intersection.