# Null space of a matrix and row echelon form

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, matrix-calculus

can we say N(A) = N(rref(A)) = N(Row echelon form A)? I was watching a video about that and instructor(khan acamdey) stated that N(A) = N(rref(A)) but not stated Row echelon form, it may be uunneccessary to emphasize that but should it be true right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the null spaces of $A$, row echelon form of $A$ and reduced row echelon form of $A$ are equal. This is because elementary row operations [preserve the null](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108041/linear-algebra-preserving-the-null-space) space of a matrix.